# Emacs: .emacs file loads but does not actually work

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I am on OSX and trying to map my command key to META. I have the following code in my .emacs file:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-escape-modifier nil)
```

Upon opening, emacs does not say that the file has not been loaded, so I'm assuming it has been loaded. What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Look in the `Messages` buffer after start-up to see if there are any errors or relevant messages.

Comment: You can issue a message from that file.  Enter something like `(message "Loading .emacs")` into the file.  After start, use `C-x b` `*Messages*` to switch to the messages buffer and see if your message appears. Maybe you want to use `~/.emacs.d/init.el` instead of `~/.emacs` these days.

Comment: I added `(message "Loading .emacs")` to the file. Now when emacs is started I get the following message: ' Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/neimamogadas/\
.emacs’: End of file during parsing: /Users/neimamogadas/.emacs'

Comment: This error only happens occasionally though, and seems to be random. When it loads, the message buffer has the "Loading .emacs" message in it, but the key bindings are not changed(ESC is still meta). I also tried using `~/.emacs.d/init.el` as you suggested(with the line removed from the .emacs file), but the message does not show up in the messages buffer, and the keybindings are still unchanged.

Comment: @nmog random stuff is always strange. Can you remove the `~/.emacs` file and move your config to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` as Stefan suggested? I am also working on a mac and I am only changing command and option keys. `(when (eq system-type 'darwin) (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta) (setq mac-option-modifier nil))`